# Program connect to server but report - error while establishing a sql connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, reportviewer

I made program and install it on client computer. On that same computer I created sql server, so it is local server.

When program is started it connect to server and load some data into datagridview. Works great, insert, update, select.

But when I go to part of program that use reportviewers, there is a problem: Report is load (empty), but when I try to fill it with data I get long error message

> "A network related or instance specific error occurred.......error 26 - error locating server/instance specified.

Connection string is in app.config and it is ok because same program already use same database. For creating report I use wizard and after that only bind it from report viewer task -> choose report.

Also, that same report work on my computer, so I think that code is ok and problem is in server or in dataset generated by wizard, but I am out of idea.

[>>>Picture of error message<<<](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NzttCyJzbkblZLMmNPbVA3TTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Error details is too long, but in this part could be something important. After this part is list of Loaded Assemblies.
[>>>Error details<<<](http://prntscr.com/8f245w)

EDIT:
Here is code, but it is generic, made by VS, not me:

```
private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet4.DataTable1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet4.DataTable1);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SviKlijentiDataSet.SviKlijenti' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.SviKlijentiTableAdapter.Fill(this.SviKlijentiDataSet.SviKlijenti);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

BIG EDIT: Problem is that my dataset does not read connection string from app.config file. How to order dataset to use connection string from app.config file?

Comment: Can you provide some code where you pass your data to your report ?

Comment: can you post details section of error shown in Picture ?

Comment: Post your connection string.

Comment: connectionStrings>
    <add name="Zavrsni" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-N6VM9KK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Zavrsni;Integrated Security=True" />    
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I would make sure the computer name in this string matches the client computer and not your computer.

Comment: I am sure about that...

Comment: Other common problem here then is the way your local SQL server is configured.  Either you don't have permissions or the server isn't set up to allow remote connections.  Not sure if remote connection is necessary since it is on the same machine but it can't hurt to try. http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/#13

Comment: Ok, I made progress... Problem is that my dataset does not read connection string from app.config file. This progress is big success for me, but I still do not know how to fix this. So, definitely that is problem. Can now someone help me how to order dataset to read connection string from app.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. Strange combination of my mistake and (I think) Visual Studio bug. Anyway:
My connection string name is Zavrsni, and all connection in code are using that string, and that was only string that I had in app.config. But, VS for datasets created ZavrsniConnectionString, and that string I didn't have in app.config file. Only when I changed my con string to something else to purposely made a mistake in program, only then that other connection string appeared in app.config file and then I realize that I have two con strings. One more strange thing, in solution properties I also had only one con string. Now everything is working.
Five days headache can now finally end. Thanks for all comments and idea.